# How to use x-delay message headers on PCF managed RabbitMQ (standard plan)

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

It seems that x-delay functionality is not working on PCF hosted service of rabbitMQ (standard plan). Used x-delay as header with 10000L as value to reply msg after 10 sec. but no success.

Can someone confirm?
(1) is x-delay works in standard plan? Does it required any settings to be enabled on management / settings section on PCF?
(2) any working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x-delay` require the [RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange). 
You can enable it when you create or update a service instance:

```
cf create-service p.rabbitmq single-node myservice \
  -c '{ "plugins": { "rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange": true } }'
```

More info:

- https://docs.pivotal.io/rabbitmq-cf/1-16/use.html#optional-plugins
- https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/rabbitmq-components.mk

**Note**: There is no way to know how many massages was delayed using this method. Consider using [dead lettering + TTL](https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/delayed-messages.html) instead.